# How to scrape the images from web pages?

Tags: java, htmlunit

I used htmlunit to scrape the images from web pages. I am beginner in htmlunit. I coded, but don't know how to get the images. Below is my code.

```
import java.io.*;
import java.net.URL;
import com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.BrowserVersion;
import com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.WebClient;
import com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HtmlPage;

public class urlscrap {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception 
    {

        //WebClient webClient = new WebClient(Opera);
        WebClient webClient = new WebClient();
        HtmlPage currentPage = (HtmlPage) webClient.getPage(new URL("http://www.google.com"));

        System.out.println(currentPage.asText());
        //webClient.closeAllWindows();      

    }
}
```

Comment: How is an image stored in an html page? Hint: what is the html tag for images?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Does this work for you??

```
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.List;

import com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.WebClient;
import com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HtmlImage;
import com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HtmlPage;

public class urlscrap {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception 
    {

        //WebClient webClient = new WebClient(Opera);
        WebClient webClient = new WebClient();
        HtmlPage currentPage = (HtmlPage) webClient.getPage(new URL("http://www.google.com"));
      //get list of all divs
        final List<?> images = currentPage.getByXPath("//img");
        for (Object imageObject : images) {
            HtmlImage image = (HtmlImage) imageObject;
            System.out.println(image.getSrcAttribute());
        }
        //webClient.closeAllWindows();      
    }
}
```

Comment: I got an SSLHandshakeException using this code; what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you're getting the text of the page, which is indeed the first step. What's your question? Are you having a problem finding all the images referenced within the page? I recommend looking up how to do DOM parsing in Java, and use it to extract all the img tags from the page.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't mind switching languages, then I would recommend Python's [scrapy](http://scrapy.org/). It is the best framework I've used so far to scrape web content, including images (it can even create thumbnails for you automatically). Personally, I would not use java for such tasks.